# KDE-connect without a 3rd device, possible?

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, android, kde-connect

**Situation**

I have two devices:

- Phone with Android 11
- Laptop with Ubuntu 20.04

I don't have a dedicated WiFi router. So, I use the phone's hotspot to access Internet on my laptop.

---

**Problem**

The devices are unable to see each other. I've configured the apps on both devices. I've tried GSConnect, looked around elsewhere on the web, but couldn't find a solution.

---

**Question**

- Is it possible to use KDE-connect in this scenario? If yes, how?
- Aren't the two devices "connected" to the "same network"?

Comment: I don't have a wifi router, and such a direct connection works for me in my Android 10 phone, with Kubuntu 20.04. Sometimes, one needs to open KDE connect settings in both the phone and the computer for them to see each other.

Comment: The setup worked for me once, on Ubuntu 18.04. I've tried it many times since, but in vain. Maybe it was just an accident from some known neighboring device.

@ArchismanPanigrahi, which phone do you use?

Comment: I have successfully used KDE Connect with Lyf Flame 8, Redmi Note 4, Redmi Y2 and Poco C3, in various DEs like KDE, Cinnamon, XFCE, in various operating systems (Xubuntu 20.04, Kubuntu 20.04, Linux Mint 20, and Manjaro XFCE)

Comment: I just ran into situation where I want to connect Android phone with Xubuntu 22.04 laptop.  If I use hotspot of the phone, some phone like a Huawei with Android 9 can not have wifi and hotspot turned on at the same time, so it doesn't work.  However, my Samsung S21 with Android 12 can have both on at the same time, so it works.  If on the other hand I use the hotspot of the laptop, even though the wifi and hotspot can not be on at the same time on my laptop, KDE connect works.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any third device.
looks like your ufw(uncomplicatedfirewall comes with ubuntu) blocking network ports

open up terminal and enter these commands and try again.

$: sudo ufw allow 1714:1764/udp

$: sudo ufw allow 1714:1764/tcp

and enter

$: sudo ufw reload

or you can try disabling ufw to check if ufw is the the problem

$: sudo ufw disable

and enable it after solving problem

$: sudo ufw enable

source : https://userbase.kde.org/KDEConnect#I_have_two_devices_running_KDE_Connect_on_the_same_network.2C_but_they_can.27t_see_each_other

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue, But i want to help anyone who will face this problem in the future. I hope this message helps everyone with that trouble.

1. First of all; when someone creates a hotspot on a phone and you connect your computer to it, your computer is not connected to the same ip address as your phone because a hotspot is a new connection. it is very different different from using a router.
2. First solution is simple,
   I personally use debian linux:

open terminal after connecting your computer to phone hotspot and run **

> `command: ip address`

**

```
username@pc-name:~$ ip address
```

in the result look for a line that starts with this format below

```
inet 192.168.112.30/24
```

and here the ip is 192.168.112.30

The last thing open kde connect app
and click on the top three dots for more options, and click on add devices by ip
click add ip, put the 192.168.112.30 in the dialog and text field and click Ok for confirming.
there you go. your device will be visible to the phone.
NB: Whenever you connect to the hotspot, do the same again. the ip address keeps changing everytime you open a hotspot. if it doesn't show up, do the same steps.

3. Third solution:
   on your android device download both kde connect and xender.
   and create a hotspot on android or ios and connect your computer to it.
   after that open xender, and click on (+) on top and click on connect pc.
   then follow on the onscreen instructions from Xender and you will see a pop up dialog saying do you want to connect this 192.168.112.30, simply copy that ip address somewhere and paste it in kde connect as I said above.
   NB: This step is for those who can't run the command. or who are not able to find their ip address for some reason am not sure of.

I hope this helps.